# "No match operator==" error when using std::equal and namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I get compile error ("no match for operator==") when using `std::equal` and my classes are define in separate namespaces (proper operators are defined).

This is my working example using `std::equal` but without namespace and there is **no compile error**

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct K {
    int a;
};

struct V {
    int b;
};


inline bool operator== (const K& lhs, const V& rhs) {
    return lhs.a == rhs.b;
}

inline bool operator== (
const std::vector<K>& lhs, const std::vector<V>& rhs) {
    return std::equal(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin());
}
```

But when I use namespace for my classes there is "no match operator" **error**

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


namespace nk {
  struct K {
    int a;
};  
}

namespace nv {
  struct V {
    int b;
};  
}

inline bool operator== (const nk::K& lhs, const nv::V& rhs) {
    return lhs.a == rhs.b;
}

inline bool operator== (const std::vector<nk::K>& lhs, const std::vector<nv::V>& rhs) {
    return std::equal(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin());
}
```

> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:1107:22: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'const nk::K' and 'const nv::V')

Also there is **no error** when `std::equal` replaced with simple loop (compare operators work well in this case):

```cpp
inline bool operator== (const std::vector<nk::K>& lhs, const std::vector<nv::V>& rhs) {
    if (lhs.size() != rhs.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    for(std::size_t i=0; i<lhs.size(); i++) {
        if (!(lhs[i]==rhs[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Codes are tested with Compiler Explorer and GCC 10.0.2 (I've also tested other GCC versions)

Comment: Presumably `nv:V` is a typo and is not in your real code, although that could cause a compiler diagnostic such as the one you observe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the library like `std::equal` can't find the `operator==` defined in global scope.

You can move `operator==` into either the namespace where `K` or `V` is defined to validate [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). (PS your 1st code snippet works because of ADL too.)

E.g.

```
namespace nk {
  struct K {
    int a;
  };  
}

namespace nv {
  struct V {
    int b;
  };  

  inline bool operator== (const nk::K& lhs, const nv::V& rhs) {
      return lhs.a == rhs.b;
  }
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/smp5qcZl7ymo7imc)